# How to sort items in listbox by IsSelected property of listboxitem in wpf?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I need to sort all items by sSelected property of listboxitem in wpf. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what your items are, so I will use integers. The idea is that the user will select the items, a button press will initiate the sort, and the selected items will be sorted, placed at the beginning of the list and then the non selected items will be added after the newly sorted items.

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListBox Name="lbData" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Height="20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

C# Code behind

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lbData.ItemsSource = new List<int> {1, 7, 2, 4, 10};

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selected = lbData.SelectedItems
                         .OfType<int>()
                         .ToList();
    if (selected.Any())
    {
        // Remove the items
        var diff = lbData.ItemsSource
                         .OfType<int>()
                         .Except(selected);

        // Sort the selected and place them at the beginning
        var ordered = selected.OrderBy(itm => itm).ToList();

        ordered.AddRange(diff);

        lbData.ItemsSource = ordered;
    }
}
```